# Getting Media items with TDS fails

Tags: tds

When trying to `Get Sitecore Items`, it shows an error for a few media items & stops at that item.

This happens for items:
 1. which have no images (and hence no alt/mime type/extension).
 2. which are of `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Movie`template.

The error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error
>   communicating with Sitecore TDS Service. Please see the Application
>   Exception Log on the Sitecore Server for more details.

Also, checked the regular Sitecore's log file and  could not find any related log. Are TDS logs saved in any other location?

Using Sitecore version is 8.2 with TDS 6.0.0.13

**UPDATE:**

I tried to follow this [solution](https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2015/12/tds-error-maximum-message-size-quota.html) to increase the size limit, but such config is not available.

The error in the Visual Studio's output pane is:

> Exception The maximum message size quota for incoming messages
>   (16000000) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
>   (CommunicationException):
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.BufferMessageStream(Stream
>   stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream,
>   BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType) 
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage
>   httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.GetItem(GetItemRequest
>   request)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.GetItem(GetItemRequest
>   request)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.GetItem(String
>   key, String sitecoreDatabase, String accessGuid, String itemIdOrPath) 
>   at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreItemNode.<>c__DisplayClass91_0.b__0(String
>   key)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.CallServiceWrapper[T](TdsServiceSoapClient
>   client, SitecoreProjectNode project, Func`2 clientCall)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreItemNode.RefreshSitecoreInfo(String
>   sitecoreItemPath)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreProjectNode.CreateSitecoreItemNode(String
>   localItemPath, String sitecoreIcon, HierarchyNode parent)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.GetItemStatus.<>c__DisplayClass19_2.b__3()
>   at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.b__0()
>
> Inner Exception Details: Exception The maximum message size quota for
>   incoming messages (16000000) has been exceeded. To increase the quota,
>   use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding
>   element. (QuotaExceededException):
>
> Exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   (NullReferenceException):    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.GetItemStatus.GetItem(CheckedSitecoreItem
>   item, Dictionary`2 createdNodes)    at
>   HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.GetItemStatus.GetItemsWorker()

Answer (score 2):

The TDS help page describes a solution for this issue: https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Help/TDS-Classic

Note that it **is not recommended to include large files in source control**. This is their answer to this type of error:

> You are probably trying to bring large file size content into your source control system. This is something that we discourage. If you have to do it, you can modify the maxBufferSize values in this file:
>
> (64 bit system)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Hedgehog Development\Team Development for Sitecore\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.dll.config
>
> (32 bit system)
>
> C:\Program Files\Hedgehog Development\Team Development for Sitecore\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.dll.config

Comment: No such config file is available at that location!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the large media file sizes. Tools like TDS and Unicorn should be specifically used to store development specific Sitecore templates, layouts, system settings, content tree, basic content etc in source control and not full fledged content. I have encountered challenges whenever we tried to manage large amounts of content in source control using TDS/Unicorn.
Larger files should be directly uploaded in higher environments like UAT etc.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me today. If you want to see detailed information about error, in Visual Studio Output pane, change `Show output from` to `Team Development for Sitecore`.

In my case, the item was getting added twice to `Model.gen.cs`. So I had to `Re-Generate Code for all items`.

Comment: The output pane pointed to a message quota but I'm not sure where to increase it. Any idea?

Comment: Don't forget this is a paid product offering by sitecore, Erick means you can submit a support ticket to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro Faniuolo's answer is mostly correct.

However, the configuration file isn't in the TDS installation folder. It's in the folder used that the extension was installed into Visual Studio. This will likely be installation specific. Note that I installed the Visual Studio 2019 version.

Mine was at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\bywmmeat.jsd\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP2019.dll.config